# I am looking to display an image when the user completes the quiz on my html page, that will place a check mark or an x image depending on the result

Tags: javascript, html, image, if-statement

I am assuming that I need to make an condition in each if statement in the javascript, but I am not sure how to get that statement to display at the end of the quiz.

I was thinking on adding an img tag at the end of each question, then make that only trigger when the quiz is complete, and the user can see the results.

```js
// Check answer to question 5
for (let i = 0; i < q5.length; i++) {
  if (q5[i].checked && q5[i].value === "b") {
    score++;
    break;
  }
}

let quizGrade = document.getElementById("quizGrade");

if (score === 5) {
  quizGrade.innerHTML = "You got 5 out of 5 correct! You have some solid Cyber Security knowledge";

} else {
  quizGrade.innerHTML = "You got " + score + " out of 5 correct. Do some more research, you got this!";
}
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a">a) Malicious Software <br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b">b) Evil Software<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c">c) Mail Software<br>

<p>2) What does the term RAT mean?</p>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="a">a) Regulatory Access Terminal<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="b">b) Random Access Timeserver<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="c">c) Remote Access Tool<br>
```

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'",`

Comment: I failed to add more of the code, I think I can add it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it :

You have to add a listener on every radio, then whenever an answer is clicked you check if it is correct or not :

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

var score = 0;
let quizGrade = document.getElementById("quizGrade");

var myFunction = function() {
    let name = this.name;
    let value = this.value;
    
    if (name == 'q1' && value == 'b') {
      score = score +1 ;
    }
    
    if (name == 'q2' && value == 'b') {
      score++;
    }
    // others response should be added here
    
    console.log(score);
    if (score == 5) {
      quizGrade.innerHTML = "You got 5 out of 5 correct! You have some solid Cyber Security knowledge";

    } else {
      quizGrade.innerHTML = "You got " + score + " out of 5 correct. Do some more research, you got this!";
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('change', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a">a) Malicious Software <br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b">b) Evil Software<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c">c) Mail Software<br>

<p>2) What does the term RAT mean?</p>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="a">a) Regulatory Access Terminal<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="b">b) Random Access Timeserver<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="c">c) Remote Access Tool<br>
<br/>
<span id="quizGrade"></span>
```